# Products of ozonolysis of 3-methyl-3-pentene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Can someone please help me explain the steps on how to predict the products?

Answer (score 2):

2-butanone and butyraldehyde, assuming you have drawn the correct substrate and made an error naming it.
Ozonolysis with DMS workup splits the double bond to give two carbonyl groups.

Comment: You shouldn't give final answer for such homework questions.